# Websocket with apache mod_proxy_wstunnel to tomcat with javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, websocket

This is my Situation:

Browser<---HTTPS/WSS--->Apache-httpd<---HTTP/WS--->Tomcat(v7)

Is it possible to get the javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate in a Servlet Filter using mod_proxy_wstunnel reverse proxy? Thats my config:

`ProxyPass /ws ws://space4-20.<***>.ch:8080/ws nofailover=On
ProxyPassReverse /ws ws://space4-20.<***>.ch:8080/ws
ProxyPass / ajp://space4-20.<***>:8009/ nofailover=On
ProxyPassReverse / ajp://space4-20.<***>:8009/`

If i connect directly to the tomcat(without apache) i can access it like this:

```
request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");
```

But with the reverse proxy i don't have any attributes.
Is it maybe because between the apache and the tomcat there is no SSL? But as I understood this doesn't matter, because if I do a normal HTTPS request i get all the SSL Information in the tomcat. I think thats because I have this: 
`SSLOptions +StdEnvVars +ExportCertData` 
But I think mod_proxy_wstunnel doesn't use that config.

Can somebody help me?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It IS because between the apache and the tomcat there is no SSL.
For "normal" HTTPS, you are using **AJP** instead of HTTP. AJP pass authentication information to Tomcat.

Your "situation" really is:
Browser<---HTTPS/WSS--->Apache-httpd<---**AJP**/WS--->Tomcat(v7)